# Bukkit - Converting a player's inventory into JSON

Tags: java, json, bukkit

I'm designing a bukkit plugin for BukkitGUI so that when you do `/bukkitguihelp inventory <playername>` it spits out the player's inventory into console. The issue I'm having is that its not reading all the slots, it's missing the first slot when printing out the JSON data. (I'm using the org.json library) JSON Contents: http://pastebin.com/L8DhNGad

```
PlayerInventory inventory = ((Player) Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(
                args[1])).getInventory();
        JSONObject mainInv = new JSONObject();

        for (int i=39; i < 0; i--) {
            ItemStack stack = inventory.getItem(i);
            JSONObject inv = new JSONObject();
            inv.put("id",Integer.valueOf(i));

            if (stack != null) {
                inv.put("amount",Integer.valueOf(stack.getAmount()));
                MaterialData stackData = stack.getData();
                inv.put("type", stack.getTypeId() + "-" + stack.getDurability());
                inv.put("name", stackData.toString());
                mainInv.put(Integer.valueOf(i), inv);
            }
            else mainInv.put(Integer.valueOf(i), "null");
        }
        System.out.println(mainInv);
```

But when I set `i < 0` to `i == 0`, it prints out `{ }` instead of the inventory JSON data. No console errors appear, and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition in for statement is incorrect:

```
i=39; i < 0; i--
```

i is set to 39. The first condition check 39 < 0 will itself fail and exit the loop.

It should be set to i > 0 or i >= 0 depending on your requirement.